# I am getting a blank page when i open my github pages link for my react app. How can i get my Github Pages for Create React App working properly?

Tags: reactjs

I have a single page react application that works perfectly fine on my local machine, but when i deploy the app to GitHub pages it runs but does not actually display my application. I know it runs because i noticed i am not getting a 404 page, or even a blank white screen but a screen with the background i chose, and when i change the background in the code and redeploy, the background gets updated. When i check the console, the only error i get is the one i attached. [image: Console log error]

and [image: File which error references]

I am trying to get the application to show up when deployed to GitHub pages rather than just displaying a blank app.

Comment: Hey Steven before your question getting negative point please share the code here by editing post or just post your code on https://codesandbox.io/ and share the code link here.

Answer (score 0):

seems the props not having movies array. use ternary operator before map statement to fix the issue

```
const MovieList = (props) => {

 ......
 .......
  return (
    <>
      {props?.movies?.map((movie) =>{
      .....
      ....
      })}
    <>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thank you i will try this, i only know the basics of ternary operator, i need to freshen up on the different use cases.

Comment: yes it avoids the issue of the black screen and it can load data, now the problem is that i cannot save to favorites, on my local machine everything works but again on the deployed app, i can only search for movies.

Comment: share the code of handling favorites, i will hep you.

Answer (score 0):

give this code an try..

```
    return(
    <>
    {props?.movies && props?.movies.map((movie) =>{
Rest of the content
}
    </>
)
```

Try this code, this will help you to get the screen, even if the data isn't there.. also thia avoids blank screen. If you still facing issue just lemme know, i will help you.
Thanks

Comment: yes it avoids the issue of the black screen and it can load data, now the problem is that i cannot save to favorites, on my local machine everything works but again on the deployed app, i can only search for movies.